# How to shuffle files and rename sequentially

Tags: batch-rename

I have a set of .png images, currently named in sequence from 1 to 1000. How can I take these images and reassign them to a random number between 1 & 1000 so I end up with the same range of sequential numbers, but the image under each number is no longer the same?

Comment: Looks a lot like a homework task.

Comment: Interesting task nevertheless ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Could be done like this:

```bsh
names=({1..1000}.png)
new_names=($(shuf -e {1..1000}.png.tmp))
for n in "${!names[@]}"; do
    echo mv "${names[$n]}" "${new_names[$n]}"
done && rename -n 's/\.tmp$//' *.tmp
```

- Create two arrays `$names` and `$new_names`
- we need to name it `.tmp` or so to not overwrite existing files, we'll fix this with `rename`.
- loop over array keys and run `mv` for each.

Note: To actually run the command, remove the `echo` and `-n` from `rename`.